# django RadioSelect widget list id

Tags: django, django-forms

I currently have a RadioSelect widget on one of my form classes that I want to style with css. However the rendered widget is contained in an `ul` and the list has no id.

What is the easiest way to add an id to the rendered list?

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `RadioFieldRenderer` and override `render` method.

[`RadioFieldRenderer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/73d6c3c5f3fd17b846219f7a5a23729f7b8f563b/django/forms/widgets.py#L661) is an object used by RadioSelect to enable customization of radio widgets.

Example implementation that adds class to `ul` element:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyRadioFieldRenderer(forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):

    def render(self):
        """Outputs a <ul> for this set of radio fields."""
        return mark_safe(u'<ul class="inputs-list">\n%s\n</ul>' % 
                u'\n'.join([u'<li>%s</li>'
                % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))
```

Usage:

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(label=_('field'),
        choices=FIELD_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(
            renderer=MyRadioFieldRenderer
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution to modify rendered html.
But you can put rendered html inside a tag with id (or a class in my case):

```
<td class="tria_tag"   >                
                    <ul>
<li><label for="id_935591-estat_0"><input checked="checked" name="935591-estat" value="2" id="id_935591-estat_0" type="radio" class="presenciaEstat" /> Present</label></li>
<li><label for="id_935591-estat_1"><input value="3" type="radio" class="presenciaEstat" name="935591-estat" id="id_935591-estat_1" /> Falta</label></li>
<li><label for="id_935591-estat_2"><input value="4" type="radio" class="presenciaEstat" name="935591-estat" id="id_935591-estat_2" /> Justificada</label></li>
<li><label for="id_935591-estat_3"><input value="5" type="radio" class="presenciaEstat" name="935591-estat" id="id_935591-estat_3" /> Retràs</label></li>
</ul>
                </td>
```

and then with jquery you can access to :

```
$('.tria_tag').each(
   function(index) {
     ul=$(this).children().first();
     ...
```