# Django radio buttons appearing as bullet point list, inside mark_safe()

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

## Background

I have used 'mark_safe()' inside a form in order to pass HTML instructions and display bullet points in my form label:

```
class FormFood(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [ (1,'Yes'), (2, 'No')]
    response = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,
              label=mark_safe("Do you like any of these foods? <ul><li>Pasta</li><li>Rice</li><li>Cheese</li></ul>"), choices=CHOICES)
```

This outputs as:

[image]

## The problem

As you can see above, bullet points are now also appearing next to 'Yes' and 'No' despite me not wanting this. Inspecting the element reveals that this is because they are also structured inside an unordered list tag (despite my ul tag ending after 'cheese' in the label above):

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for="id_response_0">Do you like any of these foods?
        <ul>
            <li>Pasta</li>
            <li>Rice</li>
            <li>Cheese</li>
        </ul>
    </label>
    <ul id="id_response">
        <li>
            <label for="id_response_0">
                <input type="radio" name="response" value="1" required="" id="id_response_0"> Yes
            </label>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="id_response_1">
                <input type="radio" name="response" value="2" required="" id="id_response_1"> No
            </label>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="FaOTY4WlVLFMl3gNtut8BJihJKub1Is0wRJRxxLck1e2eJocJVXRiGoOLDr9jdvx">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Is there a way I could stop this and just maintain the bullet points on the 'Pasta', 'Rice' and 'Cheese' whilst removing the bullet points/ list from 'Yes' and 'No'?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565744/8601641) might help.

Comment: I see, add a class and target with CSS. That should work. I was wondering if there was something more elegant I could do from the backend but a frontend fix works just as well. Thank you

Comment: Arent you ending your ul tag incorrectly? `<</ul>`

Comment: Hi MogitC, well spotted! Just ifxed that. Was a typo when transfering here rather than in my code, unfortunately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `RadioSelect` widget uses a `<ul>` element to list the options. By default, browsers display `<ul>` elements with a bullet and usually 40px padding on the left of each element.

There are three ways to fix this. You can add some basic CSS. These three methods are given in order of recommendation. The best option by far is to use CSS.

### 1. With CSS

This is the best option. Choose this one.

**First:** add a `class` attribute to your `RadioSelect` widget.

```py
# forms.py

class FormFood(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [ (1,'Yes'), (2, 'No')]
    response = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': "custom-radio-list"}),
        label=mark_safe("Do you like any of these foods? <ul><li>Pasta</li><li>Rice</li><li>Cheese</li></ul>"), choices=CHOICES)
```

**Second:** Add some CSS.

```css
.custom-radio-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

*The following methods are provided to make this answer more complete and well rounded. There are times when you will need to modify the HTML or create a custom widget. However, in your situation, CSS is the best option. Presentation should be primarily handled with CSS.*

### 2. Create a custom Widget

Creating a custom widget is pretty straight forward for simple widgets.

**First:** Create a custom widget that inherits from the `RadioSelect` class and then use that as the widget for your field.

```py
# forms.py

from django import forms


class MyRadioWidget(RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'myradiowidget.html'


class FormFood(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [ (1,'Yes'), (2, 'No')]
    response = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=MyRadioWidget,
        label=mark_safe("Do you like any of these foods? <ul><li>Pasta</li><li>Rice</li><li>Cheese</li></ul>"), choices=CHOICES)
```

**Second:** Add an HTML template that uses `<div>` elements not `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

```html
<!-- /templates/myradiowidget.html -->

{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}<div{% if id %} id="{{ id }}"{% endif %}{% if widget.attrs.class %} class="{{ widget.attrs.class }}"{% endif %}>{% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}{% if group %}
  <div>{{ group }}<div{% if id %} id="{{ id }}_{{ index }}"{% endif %}>{% endif %}{% for option in options %}
    <div>{% include option.template_name with widget=option %}</div>{% endfor %}{% if group %}
  </div></div>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</div>{% endwith %}
```

### 3. Override the default Form HTML

You can override the form widget HTML template.

**Caution: This will override the template across the entire project including the Django admin!**

**First:** Change the form template renderer to use the Django template backend.

```py
# settings.py

FORM_RENDERER = "django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting"
```

**Second:** Add your new `radio.html` file to your `template` directory to override the default widget.

```html
<!-- /templates/django/forms/widgets/radio.html -->

{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}<div{% if id %} id="{{ id }}"{% endif %}{% if widget.attrs.class %} class="{{ widget.attrs.class }}"{% endif %}>{% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}{% if group %}
  <div>{{ group }}<div{% if id %} id="{{ id }}_{{ index }}"{% endif %}>{% endif %}{% for option in options %}
    <div>{% include option.template_name with widget=option %}</div>{% endfor %}{% if group %}
  </div></div>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</div>{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Option 4: loop over the radio fields in your template, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

Comment: No need to add a custom class, you can just select the `<ul>` element id in your CSS: `#id_response`

Comment: @djvg Option 4 is the easiest solution. Works perfect.